# Checking timestamps in a constraint in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, ddl

I have created a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE Messages
(   msgID   number(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    sender_ID   number(10),
    time_sent   TIMESTAMP,
);
```

Now I want to add a constraint to it that ensures that time sent will be after the year 2014. I wrote:

```
alter table Messages
add constraint year_check 
check (time_sent > to_timestamp('2014-12-31 23:59:59'));
```

However I get the following error:

> ORA-30075: TIME/TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE literal must be specified in CHECK constraint

I don't want to have a TIME ZONE in my timestamp and have inserted values like this:

```
INSERT INTO Messages VALUES(1, 1, TIMESTAMP '2014-12-24 07:15:57');
```

How can I fix my constraint to make this error go away?

Answer (score 1):

When you lookup the error message [in the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ERRMG/e29250.htm#ORA-30075) you will see the recommendation:

> Action: Use time or timestamp with time zone literals only.

`to_timestamp('2014-12-31 23:59:59')` returns a `timestamp` (without a time zone), but Oracle requires a `timezone with time zone` in a check constraint (although I have to admit I don't understand *why*)

You can either use an ANSI timestamp literal which is resolved to a `timestamp with time zone`:

```
alter table Messages
  add constraint year_check 
  check (time_sent > timestamp '2014-12-31 23:59:59');
```

or use `to_timestamp_tz` with an explicit time zone:

```
alter table Messages
  add constraint year_check 
  check (time_sent > to_timestamp_tz('2014-12-31 23:59:59 +00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS TZH:TZM'));
```

---

Btw: I would rather change the condition to use `>=` on the first of January:

```
alter table Messages
  add constraint year_check 
  check (time_sent >= timestamp '2015-01-01 00:00:00');
```

Otherwise you could add a row with `2014-12-31 23:59:59.567`

Comment: I understand your logic here but I still get the error `add constraint year_check
               *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-02293: cannot validate (USER.YEAR_CHECK) - check constraint violated
`

Comment: @user3268401, most likely you have existing data that is before `2015-01-01`.

Comment: @user3268401: shannon is right: your existing data simply doesn't validate. You need to fix that first.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a format mask:

```
select to_timestamp('2014-12-31 23:59:59') timest from dual
  2  /
select to_timestamp('2014-12-31 23:59:59') timest from dual
                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01843: not a valid month

select to_timestamp('2014-12-31 23:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') timest from dual
  2  /

TIMEST
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
31-DEC-14 11.59.59.000000000 PM
```

Comment: Could you make it a lot more clear what you would like me to change my constraint to be?